# Django/Auth: Can request.user be exploited and point to other user?

Tags: django, security, django-authentication, authentication, http-post

Let's say i have a form that does something in database and requires user authentication that has been sent by POST, is it possible inside *request* someone evil to change the *user* in order to exploit the system?

The following example creates an item in database but requires a logged in user. Can someone send other user's data in *request.user*?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from items_core.models import Item
from items.forms import CreateItemForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def create(request):
    errors = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                Item.objects.get(
                    name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                    user = request.user
                    )
                errors = 'Item already exist. Please provide other name.'
            except Item.DoesNotExist:
                Item.objects.create(
                    name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                    user = request.user
                    )

                return redirect('items:list')

        form = CreateItemForm()
    else:
        form = CreateItemForm()

    template = {
        'form':form, 
        'items':Item.objects.filter(user=request.user),
        'request':request,
        'errors':errors
        }

    return render(request, 'items/item_create.html', template)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `request.user` object is of type `SimpleLazyObject` which is added by the `auth middleware` to the requestobject.

`SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):` is used to delay the instantiation of the wrapped class
At the time of requesting the actual logged in user, `get_user` method gets called.

```
def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user
```

Here, `auth.get_user()` would inturn validate this way:

```
backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
backend = load_backend(backend_path)
user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
```

Hence if the `request.user` object is tampered with, this validation would fail as the session data validation would fail

Comment: Isn't the user object passed in the response object as well, so that it can be accessed by templates? Is there a way for me to not pass the user object due to security issues?

Comment: @user1050619 In a middleware, you could do something like this: `del response['user']`. Also make sure you remove the corresponding context processor. More on this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 5):

`user` attribute on `request` i.e `request.user`is set by `AuthenticationMiddleware`. `process_request` for this middleware internally uses `get_user()` provided by django auth system which is defined in `django.contrib.auth.__init__.py`.

This `get_user()` uses django session and django session internally use cookies. Django session use a cookie with `key` as `sessionid`.

So, say a malicious user gets hold of the cookie of a legitimate user and sends this cookie to the server, server will think that the request has come from a legitimate user and will login as the legitimate user. But since the request was sent by the malicious user, he now has access to the resources of the legitimate user.