# Python Django login URLS and Views - Security Approach

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have this login practice in my app, it's up and running but my concerns goes to securing this login approach.

**My App URLS:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('accounts/login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

**My App Views:**

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user:
        return redirect(login_view)
    return redirect(dashboard)


def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if request.GET.get('next'):
            return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
        return redirect(dashboard)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(index)
```

in my *views.py* `index(request)`, I believe it may be vulnerable because if someone could make it and change the request and set a fake `user` it may go through ?.

I know security concepts but not expert on Django appliance approaches.

Is there a better way to do this or I don't have to change this and it's secured practice already?

Comment: You need to look at how django determines the `user` for a `request`. This is done using the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/). If your session is secure (read all the security warnings on the page linked), then no one can change the `user` of the request. This has nothing to do with what you do on your view. Note: **your dashboard view must be secured too**, read how to [limit access to logged-in users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users).

Comment: This answer can resolve your concerns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819937/django-auth-can-request-user-be-exploited-and-point-to-other-user#answer-16002639

Comment: I've already added *The login_required decorator* for *dashboard* page, is it enough ?

Comment: yes it is enough