# is it safe to compare owner_id to request.user.id for authentication in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in my app I have the model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    carbohydrates = models.FloatField()
    protein = models.FloatField()
    fat = models.FloatField()
    fiber = models.FloatField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the following serializer:

```
class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = "__all__"
```

and this viewset:

```
class MealViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Meal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MealSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Meal.objects.filter(owner_id=self.request.user.id)
```

And now I have a question, is it safe to compare `owner_id=self.request.user.id` in `get_queryset` method for authentication?

or is it possible somehow to specify user.id in request e.g. using postman and pull all Meal objects?

for example:
[Is that possible in postman or somewhere else?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1gqw.png)

I am a beginner in django and rarely used postman. Sorry if I wrote something wrong, English is not my native language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django/Auth: Can request.user be exploited and point to other user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819937/django-auth-can-request-user-be-exploited-and-point-to-other-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work. In filter, you have to write `owner=self.request.user` (preferred and safe). Or, if you really want to bother with IDs: `owner__id=self.request.user.id`.

Diving into `self.request.user` fields is a bit dangerous, because in case some *non-authenticated* user will get there — your code will crash.

Answer (score 0):

In short, in general it is safe to compare. This has been asked before: [Django/Auth: Can request.user be exploited and point to other user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819937/django-auth-can-request-user-be-exploited-and-point-to-other-user)